# My firebase query call isn't getting my document even though it exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

I'm using reactjs and my database is firebase.

I'm trying to send an invite for a group. The variables that are being passed to the function are the group's id (groupID), the group's name (groupName) which isn't used for the check but is passed onto the inviting function, and the invitee's email address (invite). It checks if an invite already exists and if not it calls the invite code, if not it just sends an alert saying the user already has an invite. This is my code for checking:

```
await props.firestore
              .collection("invites")
              .where("groupID", "==", groupID)
              .where("invitee", "==", invite)
              .get()
              .then(async (invitation) => {
                if (invitation.exists) {
                  alert("User already has invite");
                } else {
                  // Send Invite!
                  await props.firestore
                    .collection("invites")
                    .add({})
                    .then(async (ref) => {
                      SendInvite(invite,groupID,groupName);
                      alert("INVITE SENT");
                    });
                }
              });
```

The issue is its not actually grabbing anything and always sending an invite. This is how my database is set up:[image]

Comment: What exactly do you expect this code to do that's different than what you're observing?  Please edit the question to be more clear.  Bear in mind that we can't see any of the values of the variables you're showing here.  The question should contain enough information that we can reproduce the problem on our own.

Comment: Try without the exists on invitation, as well as trying logging invitation to see what is actually being received.

Comment: Can you change your code to `console.log(groupID, invite)` right before you run this query, and then edit your question to show both the updated code and its output?

Comment: I expect it to get the document in the database and then for it to do an action depending on whither it was able to get a document. In its current state it does not get any data even though it is present in the data. I have already done a console.log prior to posting, and the data I would expect to be there was there. I have already tried removing the "where" and instead directly grabbed the document with ".doc" and the code was able to get it so thus it is working.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson
The first paragraph clear states what should be happening "It checks if an invite already exists and if not it calls the invite code, if not it just sends an alert saying the user already has an invite". The text after the code snip states what is instead happening "The issue is its not actually grabbing anything and always sending an invite.". I included an image of my database so it would be possible to see what kind of data is being compared, thus it should have been obvious what kind of values was being entered.

Comment: I tried that. If I remove the exists I get the same result. The exists is there to check if the data already is in the database. I also tried checking what data was being passed and "groupID" and "invite" are being passed valid data which do match up with documents in my database. If I try simply checking what document is being grabbed I find that nothing is being found.

Comment: Bear in mind that we can't see the values of the variables you're using here, so we can't actually see that you're making a query that would match the document you're showing.  We don't have enough information to reproduce.  I suggest first hard coding the vales you expect to match, or at least console logging them and pasting them here so we can verify and reproduce.

Comment: And that is all things I have already tried before making my post. Hard coding in ".doc" instead of using "where" does return the document. console logging when I am using "where" results in no data.

Comment: Also, bear in mind though I didn't say what values where being imputed, by showing the database and saying the variables being entered should match up with those in the database I thought it would be clear that the data I was entering was also that what was in the database. Either way, the data I'm entering are groupID: "9lKZ6DkPP39Aa0ZbVS1d" and invite: "hack@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 issues preventing it to work.

Firstly, the variable "invite" appeared to be a string and acted like a string however when compared to what was in the database it would return a false. Thus, I had to modify it to `""+invite` to cast it to a string. I'm unsure why it wasn't a string to begin with.

Secondly, instead of ".exist" it should be ".empty". These are the final changes:

```
.collection("invites")
              .where("invitee", "==", "" + invite)
              .where("groupID", "==", "" + groupID)
              .get()
              .then(async (inviteData) => {
                if (inviteData.empty) {
```